# PDF-viewer in TeXstudio, ctrl+left mouse does not work

Tags: latex

I have TeXstudio installed on Ubuntu 14.04. I always could jump from build-in PDF viewer to the source by using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+left mouse, which was very convenient. But this somehow changed, now when I just click on the page in viewer, I jump to the next page in viewer instead of focusing, and I get the same effect when I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+left mouse. I cannot  jump to the desired point in the source anymore. Could not find this in the settings. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4):

The following worked in TeXStudio 2.11.2 on Ubuntu 17.04:

In the viewer, choose Window > Show > Toolbar. On the toolbar, you can toggle the zoom button or the hand button. Either way disables the click=nextpage behavior, restoring the desired ctrl-click behavior.

I don't know how you could restore the click=nextpage behavior if you wanted to, but I assume you don't.

Answer (score 2):

This is only working using the pdf chain. Under `Options` select `Configure TeXstudio` and then the option `Build`. Under `Build & View` select the `Pdf Chain` and it should work.